# ANTLR - Semantic predicate and LL(1)

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I want to make a LL(1) grammer in ANTLR that allows a multiple assigment, like:
x = y = 5;

I think semantic predicate are usefull in this situation, but the following rules won't work :(

```
    tokens {
BECOMES = '='
}

    assignment_statement
            :   IDENTIFIER BECOMES expr
            ;

        expr
            :   (IDENTIFIER BECOMES)=> IDENTIFIER BECOMES expr
            |   expr_or
            ;

        IDENTIFIER
            :   LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)*
            ;
```

ANTLRWORKS gives a NoViableAltException.

Do you know what I did wrong and how to make this work? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A grammar with a *syntactic* (not *semantic*) predicate that looks ahead 2 tokens isn't LL(1), of course.

But, you don't need a predicate, simply do something like this:

```
grammar T;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  BECOMES = '=';
}

assignment_statement
 : (IDENTIFIER BECOMES)+ expr ';'
 ;

expr
 : IDENTIFIER
 | NUMBER
 ;

IDENTIFIER
 : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)*
 ;

NUMBER
 : DIGIT+
 ;

fragment LETTER : 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z';
fragment DIGIT  : '0'..'9';
```

which would parse the input `"x=y=5;"` as follows:

[image]

but would reject input like `"x=2=3;"`.

Also, ANTLRWorks' interpreter doesn't work with any kind of predicate: use ANTLRWorks' debugger instead.

Comment: I would like to make sure that something like x=2=3; could not happen. But for you now your solution works! :) Thank you!

Comment: @user1255553, I didn't say it was. You still don't need a predicate. But why the LL(1) requirement? ANTLR is an LL(*) parser generator after all.